# Android studio won't http and NetBeans does

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some struggles using apache Http in AndroidStudio.

Searched around, tried a lot and also tested with NetBeans.

Eventually I ended up with downloading the libs manually at
https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (4.5.2.zip). Added those libs into Netbeans test project and with this code it is working fine (in NetBeans):

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:5555/test");

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "Jim"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Response message from api:

```
recived request
```

In AndroidStudio this does'nt seems to work and I just can figure out why. I added those same libs in the /libs folder.
I already found some tips I needed to add in my gradle app file so I ended up with this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.jim.app"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   //    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

   packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

This is compiling and a emulator is running fine. But when I use the exact same code to send a Http post I now get this error what doesn't make any sense to me:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.jim.app, PID: 2303
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

(Another click is working fine..)

If some does know what I am missing I'am open for suggestions.
Also, if additional info is needed, I'am happy to proved more.

**Edit**
The entire java file in Android

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private final String API_URL = "http://localhost:5555/user";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
  }

  /** Authenticate user */
  public void signIn(View view)  {

      // Test http post request
      try {
          CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
          HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(API_URL);

          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "John"));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
          httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

          CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
          client.close();
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  /** Navigate to activity Sign Up */
  public void signUp(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your method `onClick` and where do you attach them ?

Comment: This whole question **makes no sense**. Android Studio is an IDE. Are you trying to program for Android? If so, `localhost` would never work, unless you managed to create a server on your android device.

Comment: 328go Thats why you downvote? 
I know that Android Studio is an IDE, and I'am programming on Android. I have a local Api online to connect with mongo, I am not sure why this is strange to you?

Comment: Rapheal Teyssandier, Ill update my question

Comment: Why aren't you using a Networking library for this? Google Retrofit of Volley.

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 I will look into those, thanks for thinking with me here!

Answer (score -1):

If you use API 23 you should do like following to use apache library.

```
defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.jim.app"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

Comment: Will this replace my libs or do I just need to add this?

Comment: just  you have to                                                                           add  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: could you give me Android studio error log clearly ?

Comment: Using this I needed to use a other set of methods which just throw exception null and nothing more..

Comment: you may try by passing parameter in the URL directly "http://localhost:5555/user.php?username="+John+"&password="+pass+"

Comment: I think I know te problem, because the server is running local, the Android emulator cant access the url. So I am now figuring out which url I need to use :p

Comment: yes i found out it needed to be 10.0.2.0/port but still not working. Posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222753/android-emulator-communicate-with-local-api