# Android emulator communicate with local api

Tags: java, android

Working on a Android app and I have a local express api running at:

```
http://localhost:5555
```

Trying to access to a route `/test` but this doesn't seems to work with the android emulator.

I already found that I needed to change the url into `http://10.0.2.2:5555/test`

But for some reason I only get an error.

**Api route**

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("recived request");
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Gradle**

SKD version 23

Already added: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

**Code**

```
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:5555/test");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

No compile errors, *although Android says using apache.http is deprecated.*

**Expected api response (tested with java console app)**

```
recived request
```

**Actual error using code with emulator**

```
System.err: null
```

Does the emulator use some sort of a firewall/proxy I need to be aware of? Someone experienced the same result?

I hope I made my question clear, if not, I'am happily to provide extra details.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Tried libs, all getting null

- OkHttp
- Retrofit
- Volley

Comment: I don't think `response.getStatusLine()` is what you should be printing if you want the text response of your server.

Comment: Are you able to access the same url from emulator's browser?

Comment: @cricket_007 this route is just for testing purpose, The route only logs 'recived request' if a request is recived

Comment: I'm confused what is printing `System.err: null` because that is not an error.... Please show the full logcat if there is an actual error message.

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, i updated my post, the try/catch is throwing a exception containing null message

Comment: @PrerakSola I tried but it doesn't seems to access to link

Comment: Maybe you should test a get request instead of a post request and use a non-deprecated library like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried libs like OkHttp, Retrofit and Volley, all with the same outcome, null. But I haven't tried a get request yet. Thanks for thinking with me here

Comment: If the error message is null, then what exactly are you trying to catch as your exception? You should be catching an IOException, not just Exception.

Comment: @cricket_007 still getting 'System.err: null'

Comment: I suppose I missed the obvious question, what emulator are you using? On Genymotion, I have to connect to 10.0.3.2

Comment: @cricket_007 that's a good question (will update my post), using a Nexus 6 API 23 avd. Not sure if this is a Genymotion? It's from Android Studio itself

Comment: @JimVercoelen  Do not print the exception's message. Many exceptions have no message because their class name is, itself, the entire message. Normally you want to log the entire stack trace: the class name, the message, and the information about each method on the call stack. At a minimum, though, to `System.err.println(e);` so you get the class name with the message.

Comment: Also, use [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to capture the network traffic between your (emulated) android device and your server to see if anything is reaching your server and if so how it responds.  You'll want to ensure that your server is listening for requests on interfaces other than the loopback and that it will accept connections from the IP address your device connects from.

Comment: @dsh thanks for thinking with me, I'll try and print the full stack and maybee I'll get more from it. Also, using wireshark, in the api route itself, it will prent a message 'received request' to ensure it's receiving any requests. But using wireshark is a good idee to be totaly sure its receiving something. Thanks for the tip (I'll update results later)